Invalid .internal.selfref after assigning new column in previously merged data.tables
When merging two data.tables and trying to assign a new column with any object I get the following error:
Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.

I am aware, that this error is triggered by many different things and was not able to find a similar question where the error occurs after merging two tables together.
The following code produces the error in a minimal example:
table1 <- data.table::data.table(A=c(1,2,3,4,5), B=c(1,2,3,4,5))
table2 <- data.table::data.table(C=c(5,4,3,2,1), B=c(1,1,1,2,2))

table_merge <- dplyr::left_join(table1, table2, by=dplyr::join_by(B))

table_merge[, new_col := "something"]


Note that this is a warning, not an error - if you print table_merge after running table_merge[, new_col := "something"] you still get the additional column. Great question though!

Firstly, the warning can be avoided by joining with on from data.table
table_merge <- table2[table1, on="B"]

table_merge[, new_col := "something"]

table_merge
       C     B     A   new_col
   <num> <num> <num>    <char>
1:     5     1     1 something
2:     4     1     1 something
3:     3     1     1 something
4:     2     2     2 something
5:     1     2     2 something
6:    NA     3     3 something
7:    NA     4     4 something
8:    NA     5     5 something

or dplyr from there on
left_join(table1, table2, by=join_by(B)) %>% 
  mutate(new_col = "something"))
       A     B     C   new_col
   <num> <num> <num>    <char>
1:     1     1     5 something
2:     1     1     4 something
3:     1     1     3 something
4:     2     2     2 something
5:     2     2     1 something
6:     3     3    NA something
7:     4     4    NA something
8:     5     5    NA something

The package data.table treats data a bit different than base R
?data.table::copy

In ‘data.table’ parlance, all ‘set*’ functions change their input
by reference. That is, no copy is made at all, other than
temporary working memory, which is as large as one column. The
only other ‘data.table’ operator that modifies input by reference
is ‘:=’. Check out the ‘See Also’ section below for other ‘set*’
function ‘data.table’ provides.

See the reference part of an object (.internal.selfref) e.g.
attributes(table_merge)
$names
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$row.names
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$class
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

$.internal.selfref
<pointer: 0x7fe981806ee0>

which doesn't exist on a base data.frame.
Using dplyr on that data seems to create a copy which is detected by the subsequent :=, hence the warning.
